# C# cursor positioning with T.Select(T.Text.Length, 0);

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm trying to position the cursor at the end of a textbox with.....

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" 
   runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

and then

```
TextBox1.Select(TextBox1.Text.Length, 0);
```

but Visual Studio says:

```
"Error  5   No overload for method 'Select' takes 2 arguments D:\Doc\t.aspx.cs"
```

How to do it?

Many thanks.

Regards.

Gius.

Comment: I don't see any `Select()` method for `TextBox` that's in `System.Web.UI.WebControls` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx

Comment: As @Bala R said, that method doesn't exist for a `TextBox`. The reason that you are getting that message instead of `TextBox does not contain a definition...` is because `Select` is a potential extension method and VS is somehow trying to coerce the `TextBox` into using it. Replace `Select` with `Where` or `Join` and you'll get similar messages. Replace it with `Cheese` and you'll get the standard method not found message.

Comment: @ChrisHaas - I thought that too, but I can't work out which Linq implementation is getting in the way - none of the base type or interfaces for TextBox look likely to have a Linq implementation on them, and I can only ever get "'Select' is not a member..." (even with Linq to SQL, Linq to Objects and Linq to XML extension methods all in scope)

Comment: Breaking out of ASP.Net land, I can reproduce it with a standard 2010 WinForms app using `var Bob = new Object();Bob.Select(1, 1);` or `var Bob = 5; Bob.Select();`. If I create my own extension method, however, it get the expected error message. I'm thinking this might be something baked into VS, possibly optimizing on these known keywords.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that only with JavaScript. Most simple way would be to focus the textbox then add empty string to its value, on page load event. Just add this code into your `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var oInput = document.getElementById("<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>");
    oInput.focus();    
    oInput.value += "";
};
</script>
```

And it will have the desired effect as far as I can tell.
[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/zvdeF/).

Answer (score 0):

You probably read of [System.Windows.Controls.TextBox.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.select.aspx) or of [System.Windows.Forms.TextBoxBase.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4fh98s.aspx).

Sadly [System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) doesn't implement the `Select` method.